# Finding matching line in .txt document

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to get matching line, which start with "a" and end for example "140807" in dir.txt read this line and set reading data to my TextView (like this: a152z140807). I don't know why, but my code set blank text in TextView.

Even if i change

```
data = inputLine;
```

to:

```
data = "something";
```

the text in TextView is setting to blank. Thanks in advance.

```
TextView poleTextowe;

public void mButton (View view){

URLConnection nbpUrl;
String data = null;

try {
    nbpUrl = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/Kursy/xml/dir.txt").openConnection();
    InputStream is = nbpUrl.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (inputLine.startsWith("a") && inputLine.endsWith("140807")) {
            data = inputLine;
        }
    }
    is.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

poleTextowe = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pole1);
poleTextowe.setText(data);

}
```

The xml file below:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:id="@+id/pole1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/tekst"
    android:onClick="mButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pole1"
    android:text="Click"/>
```

Comment: @Decoy - he posted the link in the code. http://www.nbp.pl/Kursy/xml/dir.txt

Comment: Can you please show us the xml file where the TextView is declared ?

Comment: Have you checked if an exception is being thrown? Try adding data = "error" below e.printStackTrace(); or check your logcat

Comment: If something does not work, you can always try modifying your code to do same in other words, in this case, I suggest you do something like this: `if(inputLine.startWith("a") { Log.d(TAG,"starts a") {if ends with....}`

Comment: @Decoy I have a question: Does the reader.readLine() give same line in context of English Grammar? I believe it will give a line based on the size of buffer, so we cannot be apply the startWith() and endsWith() ligic while looping through the bufferedReader. Please do correct me if wrong

Answer (score 1):

You probably have this exception :

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Android doesn't allow you to do networking on the main (ui) thread. 
Create an async task for example to do networking tasks.

Comment: I have a question: Does the reader.readLine() give same line in context of English Grammar? I believe it will give a line based on the size of buffer, so we cannot be apply the startWith() and endsWith() ligic while looping through the bufferedReader. Please do correct me if wrong

Comment: @Eu.Dr. The Java documentation could have told you the answer to that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, your code throws an exception, to be specific, a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Which means `data` stays `null`, and nothing shows. Run it in an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`

Here's an extremely common example. Make this an inner class in your `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        //usual stuff
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        new LongOperation().execute(); //run asynctask
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "starting connection");
                URLConnection nbpUrl = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/Kursy/xml/dir.txt").openConnection();
                is = nbpUrl.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (inputLine.startsWith("a") && inputLine.endsWith("140807")) {
                        return inputLine; //because if the line's found, no need to look for other lines
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if (is != null) 
                    is.close(); //close inputstream in finally block, so it always gets closed
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "asynctask ran");
            return "NOT FOUND";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            poleTextowe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pole1);
            poleTextowe.setText(data);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question:
Does the reader.readLine() give same line in context of English Grammar? I believe it will give a line based on the size of buffer, so we cannot be apply the startWith() and endsWith() ligic while looping through the bufferedReader. Please do correct me if wrong.

Comment: I try, but this don't work. I'm beginner, could you tell me why if I change line data = input Line; to data = "some_text"; nothing was going up? The TextView don't change?

Comment: @pawel check addition. Above could works. Make sure you cover all bases and put some logs in your code.